# Turkish Character not showing in WebView android

Tags: android, webview

I am create Webview in android to show html Page, but Turkish character is not showing in android , Turkish character shows '?', how can I show Turkish character in android

```
browser.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Comment: I think you might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152789/character-set-in-webview-android

Comment: I tried but it doesn't solve my problem, I got question mark instead some Turkish characters